# A requested plan item is not enabled for this account. Plan item: foo

Tags: docusignapi

My API call receives the error

> A requested plan item is not enabled for this account. Plan item: GuidedFormsHtmlAllowed

What's the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your API call is trying to use a DocuSign feature that is not enabled on your account.

#### If you're a developer working on your developer (demo) account

Open a DocuSign support case and ask for the feature to be enabled on your developer account. If you have a production DocuSign account, then login to the [support portal](https://support.docusign.com/en/login?from=/en/contactSupport) with those credentials. Otherwise, use the [contact support page](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport) with the API Integration choice at the bottom of the page.

In either case, remember to provide your demo account ID in your request.

#### If you're working on your production account

Contact your DocuSign sales person for help to enable the feature.

Comment: Or you can create a new developer account (demo/sandbox). This particular item was added for new accounts, but may not be there for older accounts. If you still need it for your existing account - need to follow Larry's advice above...