# Proper docusign pricing plan for embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to integrate our web app with DocuSign. We expect our web app customers will authenticate and grant consent to our app to make API calls on behalf of their DocuSign accounts. Then our app will create envelopes (using access tokens to customer DocuSign accounts) and allow our app users to sign them using embedded signing.

We've built a prototype using demo account and everything works like a charm.

The only thing what is still unclear for me is how it is supposed to work after going live.

1. Am I right that our customer will be charged each envelop sending, since our integration makes call on behalf of their account?
2. Is it enough for our customer to pay for Standard eSignature Plan to make embedded signing work, or they should choose Enhanced Plans (the one where API feature is listed)
3. Should our account plan (which holds Integration Key) be at least Advanced Developer to support embedded signing?

Could anyone advise on the matter. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome! ***Please check (accept) the best answer to your question. Thank you!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Am I right that our customer will be charged each envelope sending, since our integration makes call on behalf of their account?

   A. Yes, you're right. If your customer logins in to DocuSign using their own DocuSign user account, then their DocuSign account is charged. Your own DocuSign account is not involved, at all, in this scenario. Your client id (integration key) can be used by any DocuSign account user with their own account, once they grant consent to it.
2. Is it enough for our customer to pay for Standard eSignature Plan to make embedded signing work, or they should choose Enhanced Plans (the one where API feature is listed)

   A. I don't believe that the standard eSignature plan includes support for embedded signing.
3. Should our account plan (which holds Integration Key) be at least Advanced Developer to support embedded signing?

   A. Either Advanced Developer or a "regular" eSig account that supports embedded signing. This is for your testing purposes. If you use a regular account that supports embedded signing then your other company groups can share the account for use in sending out agreements for signature.

#### Also

Please sign up as an ISV with DocuSign via https://partners.docusign.com
(no charge.) Being a registered partner provides you with additional information and enables you to use the partner use license to sell your app to DocuSign customers.

Pro-tip: use your developer account to automatically test your app. Preferably once a day. New releases are first launched on the developer system about a week before production. DocuSign has thousands of tests to guard against regression bugs. But it is possible for a bug to slip through. If you detect any issues on the developer system then DocuSign will typically stop the production deployment to fix the issue.

### Added

Re error message when a feature is not enabled: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70454579/64904).

Re which plans include the embedded signing feature: sorry, I don't have that information.

Comment: thank you for such detailed response! Am I right that "eSig account that supports embedded signing" it is not an one on the list of "predefined" here https://www.docusign.com/products-and-pricing and some "Enhanced Plans" should be negotiated?

Comment: ...and the last thing: is there any specific error code (like "ACCOUNT_LACKS_PRICING_PLAN") that you get when you are trying to generate embedded view link for the account that does not support the feature?